# Não aceita parâmetro Enum com inteiro diferente de zero

Tags: c#, tipagem, enums

Segue código:

```
class Program
{
    public enum Enum
    {
        Casa = 0,
        Apartamento = 5
    }

    public static string MinhaFuncao(Enum @enum) => "MinhaFuncao";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        var r = MinhaFuncao(0);
    }
}
```

Por que não posso colocar por exemplo: `MinhaFuncao(5);`?

O inteiro zero (0) aceita, agora diferente de zero (1, 2, 3...) não aceita.

Recebo erro:

> Não é possível converter de "int" para "Console.Program.Enum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade não deveria aceitar qualquer número, afinal um inteiro é um valor de um tipo e você espera um valor de uma enumeração, que por caso tem inteiros com valores subliminares.

A dúvida fica porque o 0 é aceito. Eu *acredito* que seja porque esse é o valor `default` da enumeração. É um valor que sempre é aceito, então funcionará sempre, mesmo que não tenha um membro com esse valor. Para os demais ele teria que verificar se o número corresponde com algum membro e essa verificação só poder ser feita em tempo de execução vai contra o que o C# prega, então ele prefere dar erro.

Comment: Tem como evitar inteiro zero no parâmetro ? Somente assim `Enum.Casa`, sem utilizar número inteiro.

Comment: Não tem, isso é uma das falhas do `enum` do C#, um dos recursos mais criticados da linguagem.